# How to import package withing package

Tags: java, import, package

I have a package named "smartApp" which further contains a TDA.java file and a sub package named "Crawler" . I am trying to access a .java file (defined in crawler package) in TDA.java.I also import Crawler package in TDA.java file as "import Crawler.*;" but it says "error: package Crawler does not exist" .

My hierarchy is as follows:
  SmartApp-->TDA.java , Crawler -->ABC.java

Comment: import smartApp.Crawler.*;

Comment: `import smartApp.Crawler.ABC;` - No issues here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It has to be:

```
import smartApp.Crawler.*;
```

Note that package names should follow the Java Naming Conventions. They shouldn't start with capital letters.

Comment: We wrote "package smartApp; import smartApp.Crawler.*;"  in TDA.java but same error. Moreoever we are running it through command line in ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

```
// Rename Crawler to smartApp.Crawler

import smartApp.Crawler.*;
```